# JavaScriptMVC applications on mac terminal commands

Tags: model-view-controller, macos, console, terminal, javascriptmvc

I am new to [JavaScriptMVC](http://javascriptmvc.com) I downloaded it and trying out my first "hello world" commands. 
The problem is all the examples are for PC's.

I am stuck at the first point. How do i write the commands in the terminal console.

In the documentation the first thing to do is to `C:\workspace\Cookbook>js jmvc\update`
How do i write this in the terminal.

Then the next command is  `js jmvc\generate\app cookbook`

Is anyone familiar, maybe i need additional plugins or add-ons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`js` is a shell script, so to run it you have to write `./` first, like this:

```
./js jmvc/update
```